# Separate single characters from an string using .split

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, arrays

I want to split a string of text into single chars excluding any kind of symbol and numbers and only allowing space with rails using split but I cannot reproduce the desired result.

Like

```
only_words_and_spaces = /[^a-zA-Z\s]/

"Hello friends".split(only_words_and_spaces)

=> ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "f", "r", "i", "e", "n", "d", "s"]
```

The regex seems to work well, but I cannot find a way to split that string into a single char array.

Comment: please accept the answer which solved your problem best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
only_words_and_spaces = /[^a-zA-Z\s]/
"Hello friends+-!".gsub(only_words_and_spaces, '').split('')
=> ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "f", "r", "i", "e", "n", "d", "s"]
```

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?

Comment: I really liked this one because it doesn't convert anything to a white space char. I'm testing this one too.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string into array liek this:

```
"Hello friends".split(//)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
 "Hello friends".split('')
```

Answer (score 1):

there are options like

"Hello friends".scan(/./)
or 
word = "Hello friends"
word.each_byte{|b| puts b.chr}

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick:

```
"Hello 32☃ friends".scan(/[a-zA-Z\s]/)
#=> ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", " ", "f", "r", "i", "e", "n", "d", "s"]
```

The original string contains numbers and the UTF-8 snowman, but they are not present in the character array.